# Python3: wait for queued item to be processed using multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x

I have a worker task (thread) which processes jobs submitted to it via a `Queue` object. Various tasks can submit jobs for this worker to process, and it is important that each submitter knows when its job is completed. The way I've achieved this is to post an `Event` object with each job, as a tuple, i.e. `queue.put((job, event))`. The worker does the job and when completed it "sets" the Event. The submitter can then wait on the event or do whatever it wants, and so it can tell that the job was completed by the worker.

This seems like a sensible way to do it.

Note, using `queue.join()` doesn't help because `join()` will block until *all* jobs have been done - and the submitter is only interested in *its* job.

What I have done, using threads, works. However, I was wondering whether I would get better performance using multiprocessing rather than threads. (The jobs are somewhat hybrid, some waiting around polling for stuff and some raw processing).

So, I tried to simply replace `threading.Thread` with `multiprocessing.Process`. Unfortunately this doesn't work since the Event object can not be pickled to send to the process on the queue. I've tried threading.Event and multiprocessing.Event, neither worked.

I get `TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects` (with threading.Events) or `RuntimeError: Condition objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance`  (with multithreading.Events).

So, how can achieve what I want to do? Any ideas?